# What can I use second chances for in the very endgame?

Tags: fallen-london

My main use for second chances was burning them for skills in the actions in the lodgings. However, my character has now reached the level cap in two of them, and I'm growing a hoard of mostly useless Confident Smiles and Hard-Earned lessons.

Is there anything worthwhile I can repeatably cash them in for? With a capped skill they're not very useful for their primary purpose. I know there's that one card in the Nadir, but that's random, and probably won't use the amount of Smiles I accumulate. That leaves handing them out to my acquaintances, but I'd still like to use the ones for skills I haven't capped for myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second chances don't exactly have a cash value; the only way to directly convert them to goods or cash is indeed The End of Battles in the Nadir.

However, that doesn't mean they're useless. There are a number of high-level challenges that are impossible to guarantee success on, even at the level cap. [These](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Dangerous#Highest_Challenges) are [listed](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Watchful#Highest_Challenges) on the [Fallen](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Shadowy#Highest_Challenges) London [Wiki](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Persuasive#Highest_Challenges), but a few examples include [manufacturing Searing Enigmas and Impossible Theorems](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/The_Other_Thing_in_the_Other_Chapel) at the University (Watchful), "What new madness is this?" on the Listing Tower opportunity card (Dangerous), or the semi-infamous ["Where did the Rosers go?"](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Where_did_the_Rosers_go%3F) on An Unlikely Garden in the Nadir, which requires 1000(!) Persuasive for a 60% chance of success. The University business, in particular, is extremely punishing -- failing the Impossible Theorem Watchful check will kill you outright, as well as cost you a hefty chunk of change and some Sudden Insights (even if you don't use any).

Second chances were also [reworked in late 2015](http://community.failbettergames.com/topic20715-announcement-another-chance-for-second-chances.aspx#post111762), such that repeatedly failing the same storylet while using Second Chances will very rapidly deplete them (1, then 2, then 4, then 8, and so on) until you either succeed or give up on using Second Chances and fail. As a result, attempting to use Chances in this manner to guarantee success on the high-level challenges will very rapidly deplete your stores.